# Find the max values within range then return the column name of that row

Tags: r, indexing

I have `data.frame` with column names start with prefix of X and series of numbers. For example,

```
col<-c("X1.1","X1.2","X1.3","X1.4","X1.5","X2.1","X2.2","X2.3","X2.4","X2.5","X3.1","X3.2","X3.3","X3.4","X3.5")
m<-matrix(sample(1:15),ncol=15,nrow=5)
mf<-data.frame(m)
colnames(mf)<-col
```

Then I want to find the max values for each row within prefix of X1 (total four columns), X2 (four columns), X3 (four columns)...and return the column number (subsequent number after the X prefix) for the max value

So my expected output is

---

```
    X1  X2  X3  X4
1    4   2   4  ...
...
```

---

Can anyone help me on this? And if there's two max values then want to return two column names as well...

I searched that `which`  should be used.. but not sure.

Comment: you are going to need to parse the column name.  You will need `strsplit` or `grep`.  Also, you can either (a) reshape the data [suggested] or (b) iterate over the groups of column names using `for` or `lapply`

Comment: Also, please consider making a reproducible example, using something like `reproduce(DATA, rows=20, cols=15)` 
Instructions are here: http://bit.ly/SORepro   -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)

Comment: ok thanks. I will do it next time. I am new to this world but learning it. it's very interesting.

Comment: edited with reproducible example.

Comment: Ricardo, can you suggest how to reshape this kind of table? So I think I need to cut them every n-th column (in this example 5th column) and append each of them to the bottom row.

Comment: Have a look at the `reshape2` package and functions like `melt` and `dcast` within that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recreate example data (please use `reproduce` or `dput` in the future):

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rep(NA,12*3),nrow=3))
colnames(df) = strsplit("X1.1 X1.2 X.3 X.4 X2.1 X2.2 X2.3 X2.4 X3.1 X3.2 X3.3 X3.4",split=" ")[[1]]
sapply(colnames(df), function(x) { df[[x]] <<- sample(1:10,3) } )
```

Get the different kinds of colnames:

```
xTypes = unique(sapply(colnames(df), function(x) { strsplit(x,"\\.")[[1]][1] } ))
```

Get the max per colname kind:

```
result = sapply(xTypes,function(x) { max(df[,grep(paste(x,"\\.",sep=""),colnames(df))])  })

> sapply(xTypes,function(x) { max(df[,grep(paste(x,"\\.",sep=""),colnames(df))])  })
X1  X X2 X3 
 9  9 10  9
```

If you want the column index of the maximum within each colname kind:

```
result = sapply(xTypes,function(x) { which.max(apply(df[,grep(paste(x,"\\.",sep=""),colnames(df))],2,max))  })
names(result) = xTypes
```

Now the result is:

```
X1  X X2 X3 
 1  1  2  1
```

Comment: Thanks. code looks so efficient. But I want the returned values as column index, not the max value itself. How do I index the column name for the max values??

Comment: I added it to the code, have a look at the implementation detail, it is the only way to get the hang of it. Also Ricardo is right, your data should not be in this format in the first place it is easier to have each observation stacked on a separate line. You can always do aggregation, summaries, etc. later.

Comment: i see. I will then find a way to modify my table.

Answer (score 2):

To reshape your data use the following:

```
library(reshape2)
mf.melted <- melt(data=mf)
mf.melted$group <- unlist(gsub("\\.\\d+$", "", as.character(mf.melted$variable)))
mf.melted
```

#### Disection of this line: `unlist(gsub("\\.\\d+$", "", as.character(mf.melted$variable)))`

```
## Original column names are now stored as column `'variable'` in `mf.melted`
mf.melted$variable

## Notice it is a `factor` column. So needs to be converted to string. This is done with:
as.character(  __  )

## Next we remove the `.3` (or whatever number) from each.
## the regex expression '\\.\\d+$' looks for 
`\\.`  # a period
`\\d`  # a digit
'\\d+' # at least one digit
`$`    # at the end of a word

## gsub  finds the first pattern and replaces it with the second
## in this case an empty string
gsub("\\.\\d+$", "",  __ )

## We then assign the results back into a new column, namely `'group'`
mf.melted$group <-   __
```

Now, with your melted data.frame, you can easily search and aggregate by column group

```
head(mf.melted)
  variable value group
1     X1.1     3    X1
2     X1.1     4    X1
3     X1.1    12    X1
4     X1.1    14    X1
5     X1.1     7    X1
6     X1.2     6    X1
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. And Thanks for the line comments. very helpful to understand..

Comment: @kclick, no prob, glad to help